# UDF not working with external variable [Java-spark]

Tags: java, apache-spark, groovyshell

I am trying to execute the following code.

I am taking a dataset as input, doing some operation on it using Groovyshell and adding that result to the new column in dataset.

```
private static Dataset<Row> addDebitCreditCol(SparkSession sparkSession,Dataset<Row> df,String code){
        Script script=new GroovyShell().parse(code);
        UDF3 rulesExecutingUDF = (UDF3<Double, String, String, String>) (val1, val2, val3) -> {
            Binding binding = new Binding();
            binding.setVariable("val1",val1);
            binding.setVariable("val2", val2);
            binding.setVariable("val3", val3);
            Object value = script.run();
            return value.toString();
        };
        sparkSession.udf().register("rulesExecutingUDF",rulesExecutingUDF,DataTypes.StringType);
        df=df.withColumn("NEW_COL",callUDF("rulesExecutingUDF",col("val1").,col("val2"),col("val3")));
        return df;
    }
```

When I execute this code, it throws an error saying

> User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable. Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: Script1

It looks like I can't use an external variable(which is Script here) inside a UDF. What other alternatives do I have?

I have tried getting this external variable to work somehow but it didn't worked, and I am unable to find an alternative to UDF which can do this.

Comment: Can you try moving `Script script=new GroovyShell().parse(code);` inside the udf?

Comment: I was doing that only earlier. But the issue is for every record I need to make a new Groovyshell, and it was creating some issues. That's why I had to take out this out of loop.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to solve this may be to use a [script base class](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-2.5.10/html/documentation/#_custom_script_class) that implements `Serializable` itself.

```
public static abstract class BaseClass extends Script implements Serializable {

}
```

And then use that class as the superclass of your script:

```
CompilerConfiguration config = new CompilerConfiguration();
config.setScriptBaseClass("stackoverflow.Main.BaseClass"); //use your FQCN
Script script = new GroovyShell(Main.class.getClassLoader(), config).parse(code);
```

This will make `script` a `Serializable` instance. If you test `script instanceof BaseClass` and `script instanceof Serializable`, they'll both return `true`.